# PHP Mongodb - Sort Query based on nested objects

Tags: php, mongodb

I am fairly new to *PHP* and working with a *MongoDB*, so please be patient :)

This is an example of what I am trying to do, not the actual data, so hopefully this helps!

I have a *MongoDB* Collection that has nested objects in it and I want to sort the results of a query based on one of the nested fields.

Sample row from the DB via *MongoDB Compass*:

```
_id:"12345"<br>
houses:Object<br>
  > 124 Happy St.:Object<br>
    > name:"124 Happy St."<br>
    > price:"$123,000"<br>

  > 123 Happy St.:Object<br>
    > name:"123 Happy St."<br>
    > price:"$124,000"<br>

  > 125 Happy St.:Object<br>
    > name:"125 Happy St."<br>
    > price: "$200,000"<br>
```

I want to be able to sort my query based on the price field (highest to lowest) in the houses object.

I've tried the following but I can't see to get the results to return sorted as expected - remember, I'm not that strong yet with *PHP* and *MongoDB* so go easy on me :P

```
$houses_query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([ "_id" => "12345" ], [ 'sort' => [ 'houses.price' => 1 ]])
```

Is there a way to filter the query or do I have to read the rows into an array and sort that way?

Comment: Are you familiarized with the MongoDB’s aggregation framework? Take a look at the unwind operation, you will be able to apply a sort function then.

Comment: I looked into it, but am not sure how to apply it to the Query.  I'll keep searching

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, mongoDB has a robust sort algorithm and tools like sort, order_by etc. You can do with php arrays but mongoDB has a lot of blessings :)

I did similar solution nowadays, you could do like this (your mongo class can be diffrent)

```
$videos = $this->mongo_db->where(
array('$text' => array('$search' => $q), 
'status' => 1))
->order_by(array('video_sales' => 'desc'))
->get('videos');
```

Mongo documentation says to us;

```
db.collection.find().sort( { age: -1 } )
```

> Deprecated in the mongo Shell since v3.2
>       Starting in v3.2, the $orderby operator is deprecated in the mongo shell. In the mongo shell, use cursor.sort() instead.